# Checking multiple columns from a table against a column in another table

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2007

**Table A**
Name,
Address,
...,
Item1,
Item2,
...,
Item10

**Table B**
ProductID

I want to run an SQL statement (in access) to Select all records where any item ([Item1] - [Item10]) that does not match a Product code found in [ProductID] in Table B. I am trying to catch all errors in the file before I export it into our inventory software and it can not find the item and we have to start over.

I have been trying to make a LEFT JOIN work but with no success.

Comment: I do believe that you are looking for a NOT IN query.  How is Table A linked to Table B?

Comment: If you have Item1, Item2, ..., Item10, then your database is not well normalized.  Seeing how you are transitioning, now would be a good time to make an Item table.

Comment: The Item1, Item2, ..., Item10 are how our client sends us the file. We just Imports it in since they have a couple hundred items but they only send us what the customer requested. The items fields are only to be used for Item codes they have. It is not a set Item in that field. I hope I am explaining this better

Comment: They are not linked currently

Comment: MS Access 2007 but using SQL coding in Access as Access has a lot of limitations on queries

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For [TableA]...

```
ID  Name   Item1     Item2     Item3   
--  -----  --------  --------  --------
 1  Name1  Product1  Product2  Product3
 2  Name2  Product2                    
 3  Name3  Product1  Product4          
 4  Name4  Product1  Produtc2  Product3
```

...and [TableB]...

```
ProductID
---------
Product1 
Product2 
Product3
```

...the query...

```
SELECT * FROM TableA
WHERE IIf(IsNull(Item1), False, DCount("*", "TableB", "ProductID='" & Item1 & "'") = 0)
    Or IIf(IsNull(Item2), False, DCount("*", "TableB", "ProductID='" & Item2 & "'") = 0)
    Or IIf(IsNull(Item3), False, DCount("*", "TableB", "ProductID='" & Item3 & "'") = 0)
```

...produces:

```
ID  Name   Item1     Item2     Item3   
--  -----  --------  --------  --------
 3  Name3  Product1  Product4          
 4  Name4  Product1  Produtc2  Product3
```